# LINQ: Dynamic predicate builder issue

Tags: linq, entity-framework, dynamic, predicate, predicatebuilder

I'm trying to create a helper class to easily build dynamic LINQ queries. Code is heavily modified version of this excellent CodeProject article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/493917/Dynamic-Querying-with-LINQ-to-Entities-and-Express which uses the PredicateBuilder here: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

I'm still in the process of cleaning up the code so variables names are rubbish at the moment and there is not one comment in sight.

**Usage**

```
    Dim conditions As New List(Of Condition)
    With conditions
        .Add(New Condition With {.Field = "EatsPeople", .Operator = "Equals", .Value = False})
        .Add(New Condition With {.Field = "Name", .Operator = "Equals", .Value = "Adric"})
        .Add(New Condition With {.Field = "Description", .Operator = "Contains", .Value = "ugly"})
    End With

    Dim predicate = BuildPredicate(conditions)
    Dim tester = data.Monsters.AsExpandable.Where(predicate).ToList
```

**Entity**

```
Public Class Monster
    Public Property EatsPeople As Boolean
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Description As String
End Class
```

**Storage for search**:

```
Public Class Condition
    Public Property Field As String
    Public Property [Operator] As String
    Public Property Value As Object
End Class
```

**Methods**

```
Public Function BuildPredicate(conditions As List(Of Condition)) As Expression(Of Func(Of Monster, Boolean))

    Dim predicate = PredicateBuilder.True(Of Monster)()
    For Each c In conditions
        Dim dbFieldName = c.Field
        Dim dbType = GetType(Monster)
        Dim dbFieldMemberInfo = dbType.GetMember(dbFieldName, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase Or BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Instance).Single()

        predicate = BuildExpression(c, dbType, dbFieldMemberInfo, predicate)
    Next
    Return predicate

End Function

Private Function CreateLambda(value As Object, method As MethodInfo, ByVal dbType As Type, ByVal dbFieldMemberInfo As MemberInfo) As Expression(Of Func(Of Monster, Boolean))

    Dim dbTypeParameter = Expression.Parameter(dbType, "x")
    Dim dbFieldMember = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(dbTypeParameter, dbFieldMemberInfo)
    Dim criterionConstant = New Expression() {Expression.Constant(value)}
    Dim containsCall = Expression.Call(dbFieldMember, method, criterionConstant)
    Return TryCast(Expression.Lambda(containsCall, dbTypeParameter), Expression(Of Func(Of Monster, Boolean)))

End Function
```

**And the problematic method**

```
Private Function BuildExpression(condition As Condition, ByVal dbType As Type, ByVal dbFieldMemberInfo As MemberInfo, ByVal predicate As Expression(Of Func(Of Monster, Boolean))) As Expression(Of Func(Of Monster, Boolean))

    Dim type = condition.Value.GetType
    Dim method As MethodInfo = type.GetMethod(condition.Operator, BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.Public, Nothing, {type}, Nothing)

    If type = GetType(String) Then

        If condition.Value.ToString.Contains(",") = True Then

            Dim inner = PredicateBuilder.False(Of Product)()
            For Each v In condition.Value.ToString.Split(",")
                inner = inner.Or(CreateLambda(v, method, dbType, dbFieldMemberInfo))
            Next     
            *****Return predicate.And(inner)*****
        End If

    End If

    Return predicate.And(CreateLambda(condition.Value, method, dbType, dbFieldMemberInfo))

End Function
```

**What is the problem?**

The line in the last method surrounded by five asterisks is the issue.

When adding the OR grouped expression to the original predicate builder you get

> The parameter 'f' was not bound in the specified LINQ to Entities
>   query expression.

For some reason, I can't seem to create a nested expression.
If you put the code above where the query is executed in usage sample, it works (after making some mods).

**Update with solution:**

The line with the asterisks needs to change to 
`Return predicate.And(inner.Expand)`

Comment: Thanks Aaron for the tip. Want to make an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Done - glad I could help. What did the Visual Basic implementation look like by the way? You could edit your question to include this for the benefit of future generations :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a Visual Basic person, but in the C# implementation I think you'd probably need to add AsExpandable() to your query as per albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx.